# How can I get webcam field of view in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webcam

I'm developing an app which uses device camera. I need to know FOV of device camera. How can I get it by script?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a function for that in Unity. You can get the FOV of a virtual Camera (Camera.fieldOfView), but since you can't really calculate a real Camera's FOV, there's no Way for simply getting it via Unity (as far as I know). If you need the FOV really badly and you're working with an android 5.0 device or newer, you could somehow get the sensor size using the android API's [camera characteristics](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#SENSOR_INFO_PHYSICAL_SIZE). Then you could get the focal length of the camera from the metadata of an example photo taken with it. Using the sensor size and the focal length, you could (according to [this article](https://scantips.com/lights/fieldofview.html) i found) then roughly calculate the FOV. Or if you just need it roughly, you could do the same but instead of using the android API, simply use an average sensor size (maybe 36mm x 24mm). But thats all just speculation, I don't know much about cameras and how percise the calculations would be. Maybe there indeed is a simpler way that i didn't found, but if not, you should propably try to work arround this problem. Maybe you could use an average FOV or something like that...

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for my case. I'm using Vuforia in my project. I can write

`Vuforia.CameraDevice.Instance.GetCameraFieldOfViewRads();`

GetCameraFieldOfViewRads returns vector2; Its first parameter is vertical field of view and the second one is horizontal field of view.